# How to change the document mode of application from IE quirks to IE 9 in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am facing this issue in IE9:

> 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'.

The line of code is:

```
l.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",I,!1),
```

To my knowledge jQuery 2.1.1 supports to IE9 and above. My application is in ASP.Net and want to upgrade jQuery 1.4 to 2.1.1. I tried by using below code right after the opening Head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9">
```

It did not work.

Does anyone know of a solution to resolve this issue or we can set this in config file too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's corresponding 'l' in your code ?

Comment: have you try `content="IE=edge"` instead of `content="IE=IE9"`?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Specifying Legacy Document Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx), the value of the content attribute should be `IE=9`.

Note that if this is deployed across an Intranet, you may also need to change the [compatibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277) on the client.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

P.S. If setting content to `IE=9` doesn't work, then something's getting in the way, e.g. syntax error, group policies, other settings.  Merely changing the value of content to `IE=edge` won't make much of a difference.