# Using X-UA-Compatible to emulate IE9 in corporate setup

Tags: html, internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

I have been reading up about document type emulating and compatibility mode in IE and have to say its quite a bit to get one's head around.

I have developed an App with Bootstrap 3 and Ember rendering a few pages controlled through a menu.

I tested this in all browsers, Webkit, Moz, and IE and all seemed perfect. I work in a large corporate, so when I decided to test it on some of my colleagues' computers, on IE, I got a blank page. Now I found that very strange because they were all running IE10 or IE11, although there is the odd IE9. I couldnt understand it because it renders perfectly on my IE.

So anyway, I started hitting F12 on their browsers and realised that many of them had IE7 emulating even though they were running IE10 or 11.

I read a bit about this issue, and I found the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

So I proceeded to add this line to my page so it is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Now my question is this: Am I correct in assuming that if there was some sort of group policy set when using IE at work, that this workaround would solve the issue?

I will do some testing tomorrow morning, but just wanted to know if that is along the right lines?

Many people at work use Chrome and Firefox or whatever they want to, but there are obviously quite a few that use IE.

Comment: i believe group policy will win. I had an issue with an intranet app where ie had the checkbox "enable compatibility mode for intranet apps" checked. Http headers, meta tags, nothing worked. We had to uncheck that box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that there must be a reason why the current group policy is set to enable compatibility mode (some other intranet app maybe) and that other app might stop working (or render badly) if you disabled it. If the admin have configured it in a way where that there's a Compatibility View list then you're in luck because all you need to do is not include your web app's URL into that list.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622935(v=vs.85).aspx

As for the document mode, I suggest for you to use this instead:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

> Setting the version to 'IE=edge' tells Internet Explorer to use the
>   latest engine to render the page and execute JavaScript.

https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible

The only reason you want to "IE=EmulateIE9" is that your app is targeting the legacy document mode which in your case it isn't since you're using the latest web frameworks out there. I assume you want the best UI experience for your users.

I understand that in your case the IE versions vary and that some might not support "IE=edge". It will be just OK because it will fallback to the highest supported document mode. For example, IE8 with IE=9, IE=Edge, or IE=EmulateIE9 results in IE8 mode.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405771(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

IE uses different [security zones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537183(v=vs.85).aspx) for different types of content.  Stuff from the Internet is loaded in the Internet zone.  Stuff from the local network is loaded in the Intranet zone.  If you go through Internet Options, you can see that there are different [security settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537186(v=vs.85).aspx) applied to the various zones.

If you're deploying the app through the network, then your app is likely loading the app in the Intranet zone (right click the page and then choose Properties to confirm).

By default, IE loads intranet pages in compatibility view, which is the same as using EmulateIE7 as the content value for the x-ua-compatible element.  This means that, absent additional tagging/changes, your app is being treated as if it were being viewed in IE7.

If you need a specific document mode, you should be able to specify that mode directly in the content value, e.g, `content="ie=9"`.  If that doesn't help, then try [adding an MotW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) to the page, so that the page is loaded in the Internet zone.  In turn, this should allow the x-ua-compatible setting to take effect.

You can also change the [Compatibility View Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277), provided they're not disabled through GPO, so that Intranet pages aren't automatically loaded in compatibility view.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Hi. Thank you all for the comments it is really helpful. Just a note  - although the app will ultimately run on a server/intranet, I was testing it from a USB stick, i.e.just opening the html file and not running it off a server. (ember allows you to do that).

Comment: USB stick will still be seen as a local file resource; you'll either get Intranet zone or the Local File zone (depending on IE version).  The points are the same; it's still a separate security zone and will (likely) be treated similarly to the Intranet, thus the recommendations still apply.  (There are differences, but I don't think many are worth mentioning here.)