# HTML tags closing early

Tags: html

Started working with HTML and most tags keep closing early when loaded in a browser.

When I found the issue I tried going back and making a more simple example shown here but discovered that even the closing tags that I wrote into the code are getting their own closing tags generated for them. Found this out while trying to learn CSS and none of the tag names were working because they were immediately getting closed off. I also put the HTML into W3C validation to try and find any issues but did not find anything obvious.

This is what I saved as an .html file and opened in my browser (Internet Explorer 11 - have to use this at work).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h2>Testing</h2>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <p>This is a footer test</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Going into Developer Tools to view the code it is running like this.

```
<!--DOCTYPE HTML-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  <head>
  <body>
    <section></section>
    <h2>Testing</h2>
    </section><//section>
    <footer></footer>
    <p>This is a footer test</p>
    </footer><//footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected 'h2' to be inside 'section' and 'p' to be inside 'footer', but they are being closed off and are not in those tags. I'm still fairly new at HTML and didn't discover this until I was trying to add some CSS and wasn't able to style tags the way I thought I could.

Edit: Unchecking "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" on Compatibility View Setting immediately fixed it.

Comment: Make sure you use a browser that supports HTML5 and set the appropriate compatibility mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 not recognizing HTML5 elements when loading a page from my desktop, any ideas why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588545/ie11-not-recognizing-html5-elements-when-loading-a-page-from-my-desktop-any-ide) or [IE11 Document mode defaults to IE7. How to reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27272454/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon ... and yet, [Microsoft may never end support of IE11](https://medium.com/@burger.neal/the-end-of-life-of-internet-explorer-11-12736f9ff75f)... (insert crying emoji).