# IE11 Compatibility Mode uses IE7, but need IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-11

within a web app IE11 renders the site using ie7 mode.
But it should use ie8 mode.
The web app uses correct header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Any compatibility setting in IE11 always let him use IE7 mode.
Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's IE7 and not quirks mode (see also https://alastairc.ac/testing/IE_Doctypes/)?

Comment: Developer Tools show "Internet Explorer 7 (default)"

Comment: Is it in an iframe? X-UA-Compatible doesn't do anything on iframes, only on the parent page.

Comment: Is the content hosted on the file system or a network resource?  If so, are intranet sites set to [display in Compatibility View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277)?

Comment: It is not an iframe.
It is hosted on IIS in the intranet. 
Display intranet site in comp. view is set.