# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/> tag is not working on production environment but works in the staging environment

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

I have a .aspx file that has a X-UA-Compatible tag that will make the document mode of IE to 8. 
This works fine in our staging environment, but in our production environment this meta tag is not working.

I've compared the Web.config file of both environment and there's no configuration for X-UA-Compatibility like this.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Because we want only a specific .aspx file to be rendered in IE8.

Does anyone know what might be the cause of the meta tag not being recognized by the IE?
I also compared the code via DOM Explorer and they both contain the tag we explicitly put

```
<META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=8>.
```

But still in our production environment the IE Document mode is still set as Edge which is by default. It should be rendered as 8 via X-UA- compatible meta tag, which works fine in our staging.

Thank you for the help.

[This is the document mode in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrDj5.png)

[This is the document mode in staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da8AF.png)

Comment: If the file is served from the Intranet (right-click the page, choose Properties, and then check the value of Zone), then you're likely running into the default of "[Show Intranet Pages in Compatibility View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277)".  You can change this by either changing the setting on each client or by adding an MotW to the page that [renders it in the Internet Zone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx).  (Note: This assumes there aren't any competing GPOs or other factors.)

Comment: Hi Lance, Show Intranet Pages in Compatibility View is not checked.