# Override meta compatibility header tags internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, tags, compatibility

Hello I've been searching forever now to try to find a way to have IE completely ignore the custom compatibility meta tags in a page as it is causing issues on some of our client's machines but not enough for my development team to change the meta tags to use edge.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Does anyone know of a way to have IE11 override these tags so that I can just configure a fix on the machines running into the issue? Once I switch the Document mode in IE Dev tools to use "edge" instead of IE8 the problem is resolved, but when they return to the page again after closing the browser and re-opening the page defaults back to IE8.

I've looked into the possibility here [Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/will-the-ie9-webbrowser-control-support-all-of-ie9s-features-including-svg/5357168#5357168)

but I tested and it doesn't seem to work for ignoring the custom meta tag in the `<head>` of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, `x-ua-compatible` headers specified in the page are [considered canonical](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676917(v=vs.85).aspx).  That is, the page has the last word, regardless of other changes/settings.

In your case, however, you may be able to change things by adding an HTML5 doctype ('`<DOCTYPE html>`) as the first line of your page.  Your existing `x-ua-compatible` says (basically) "rely on the DOCTYPE to figure out how to render the page."

If you're not getting "edge mode" now, it's likely that you're either not using a DOCTYPE (which triggers quirks mode by default) or you're using a DOCTYPE that [triggers quirks mode by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955379(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also, if your pages are deployed across the Intranet, you may want to consider adding a "[Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx)" (MOTW) to the page that opens them from the Internet Zone.  (By default, IE opens [Intranet pages in Compatibility View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277), aka emulate IE7 mode.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance