# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> is not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, x-ua-compatible

In our application we are using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` as the first line of code inside `<head>`tag. In Local and QA it is working fine, but when we try to open PROD in IE we are facing some problem - it is opening in document mode 7. In IE EDGE it is working fine, we are facing this issue in IE 11.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If:

- The production environment is in the Intranet zone (right-click and then choose Properties), and
- The page does *not* contain a `<!DOCTYPE>` directive, and
- The Default settings have not been changed

([Other factors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676914(v=vs.85).aspx) may also be involved.)

Then, the page is likely loading in IE7 Compatibility mode [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277).

If you cannot change the page to include the HTML5 doctype directive (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), then you might see if the [web server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913(v=vs.85).aspx) can serve the `x-ua-compatible` header with the page.