# IE: Conditionally set Document Mode based on Compatibility Option

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web, compatibility

I'm working on a legacy system that has a mishmash of browser dependent features (don't ask).  The plan is to revamp everything to be current, but in the meantime, I need to figure out a way to make the following happen:

If the user has Browser Mode set to compatibility mode for this site or in general, I need to make the Document Mode IE8.  This specific case I'm looking into, I'm using IE10.  When you switch to IE10 Compatibility mode, the "page default" for the Document Mode is Internet Explorer 7.  If I could just make the page default Internet Explorer 8, I think that would solve my case for now.

When I try to use  in the header, it ALWAYS forces to IE 8 compat mode.

I realize this is a very strange way to do things, and it's only temporary until I can properly fix the insanity....

Answer (score 1):

Which IE8 mode do you want?  IE8 Standards mode or IE8 "use the `<!doctype>`" mode?  If the former, set `x-ua-compatible` to `IE8`.  If the latter, set it to `EmulateIE8`.  (The various options, in gory detail, [can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).

(The first value specifically chooses IE8 standards mode as the target mode; the second will pick IE8 standards mode if the page contains a standards mode `<doctype>` or IE5 quirks mode if the page doesn't contain a `<doctype>`.)

The key is knowing which legacy document mode that you need for the page. Figure that out and target that mode specifically.  (Use the Emulation tab of the Developer Tools to switch between modes until you find the one that works.)

Note that if you deploy the page to an Intranet (right click, choose Properties, and then check out the Zone value), you may wish to add a [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) to the page so that it opens in the Internet zone and avoids the [various defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277) that behave otherwise.

Comment: Some users force browser mode = "IE 10 Compatibility" for the site.  For those users, I would like the default Document Mode to be IE 8.  I don't want to force anyone else to use any other browser.  Which is why I don't want to use the x-ua-compatible since it forces all browsers to IE8/EmulateIE8.  

What do you mean by use the <!doctype> mode?    

My biggest curiosity, is when I do manually choose Compatibility mode, what is it that makes IE7 the "Page Default" document mode.  And is there any way I can make the Page Default IE8 instead.