# ASP.NET Core website home page is displaying different on IE - works fine on Google Chrome

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

For a test, published a test website on `IIS 8.5` in `Windows Server 2012 R2`. It's a custom website (not under built-in Default Web Site of IIS). When we browse the website on company network using `http://CompanyName.com/TestWebApp`, it displays the familiar default home page of .NET Core test website `correctly` on `Chrome` as shown in figure 1 below. But the same url displays the home page differently on `IE 11` as shown in figure 2 below. **Question**: What we may be missing here and how we can make the home page display correctly in IE as it is doing in Chrome?

**Note**: We've tried restarting IIS, clearing the cache in the browsers but still the same issue only on IE.

**Home Page in Chrome** [using URL: `http://CompanyName.com/TestWebApp`]

[image]

**Home Page in IE 11** [using URL: `http://CompanyName.com/TestWebApp`]

[image]

**UPDATE**:

The console tab of the Developer tool (F12) of IE gives the following error. I tried suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27272454/1232087) but it did not help:

> The attached page targets document mode 7. some console apis and features may not be available

Comment: F12 to open developers tools and check if all files were successfully downloaded.

Comment: Internet Explorer is mostly behaving differently to other browsers.

Comment: @Powel To answer your question, I've added an **UPDATE** section to the post so other readers can also benefit.

Answer (score 0):

On IE, go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings and disable the Compatibility View.

For example, for the Intranet site, uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"