# How to set document mode default version IE-7 to IE-11 with Application?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

I am using IE-11. And I am implementing application. So when I am opening with localhost then it is opening with IE-11, But When I deployed in server and then it opening with IE- version 7. I have seen one link but my problem is not solved([IE11 Document mode defaults to IE7. How to reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset)). I am attaching one screen shot for the version in console.

**Default set IE-11 with localhost**
[image]

**Default set with in deployment**
[image]

I am selecting 11 version from console. But when I close the console then again it become a default value 7. I want to set default value 7. Only my application taking & default value. I have checked other website Qoura, https://www.winni.in/ these are taking default version IE-11. only my application taking 7default valie in DEV. I want to set default value 11.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

by default will show you lastest version of internet explorer (11)

If you can do it with another version, just edit the content tag, for example, Internet explorer 9 ("IE=9") :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```