# GWText application doesn't work on IE11

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I have an application which is developed using gwtext 2.0.5 , it used to work in IE9 but it doesn't work in IE11. It doesnt show any error message.
Request does go to backend code but when from my code request is forwarded to a page, nothing is displayed. It seems my *.nocache.js is not being loaded.

I tried changing meta tag `X-UA-Compatible` to `IE=EmulateIE8` and adding user.agent in `*.gwt.xml` but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your `.gwt.xml` file?

Comment: Here it is :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='imwt'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.gwtext.GwtExt'/>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP"/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
    <entry-point class='com.bnpp.client.IMWT'/>  
   <stylesheet src="../js/ext-2.0.2/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script src="../js/ext-2.0.2/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" />
  <script src="../js/ext-2.0.2/ext-all.js" />
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
</module>

Comment: Did you check in Developer Tools? Any error or something?

Comment: got error - Object doesn't support property or method 'createContextualFragment' . Added following code to resolve it -               if ((typeof Range !== "undefined") && !Range.prototype.createContextualFragment){    Range.prototype.createContextualFragment = function(html)
    {        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
        div = document.createElement("div");
        frag.appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = html;
        return frag;    };  }                                                                                                             but it didn't help

Comment: I changed Document Mode(in Developer Tools) in IE11 to Edge and it worked. I dont know how but my application always Defaults to Document Mode 8 in IE11.
I tried chnaging "X-UA-Compatible" in my index.jsp to different value(Edge, EmulateIE8, EmulateIE9) but still IE11 always opens my application with Document Mode 8. I cant ask client to change document mode everytime after opening my application in IE11 to make it run.
Is there a way to set specific Document Mode for IE11 ?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot. This happened in one of my previous project as well. I had to change "Document Mode" everytime I open my app url in new tab/window. I wasn't using GWT, I used only HTML / CSS. Do one thing. Edit your question and ask about this problem. Change the subject line accordingly, too. Also search for this Document mode change problem instead of GWT app not working.

Comment: Thanks @RAS. I found lot of Answers on this site for Document mode change problem but none is working. I am following up with my networking team to change the LAN settings as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034924/how-to-set-ie11-document-mode-to-edge-as-default