# IE11 Document mode defaults to IE7. How to set as edge?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11

I have try to fix as following steps but no luck, after close IE window it show the default 7.

Try these things:

1. - Press <Alt> to display the IE menu.
   - Choose Tools | Compatibility View settings
   - Remove the checkmark next to Display intranet sites in Compatibility View.
   - Choose Close.
2. I unchecked the "Automatically detect settings" in the Local Area Network Settings (found in "Internet Options" > Connections > LAN Settings.
3. using a meta tag as follows:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
   ```

To remove a site from this list, follow these instructions.

1. Go to Tools > Compatibility View settings.
2. In the resulting dialog, click on the site you want to remove from the list.
3. Click the Remove button.

And then select edge from emulation.

This problem is coming with particular PC to open my website.

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: 1. You need to fix your formatting. 2. Is this a website you own? If so what is the relevant header tags? If not this question is probably better suited to [SuperUser SE](http://superuser.com)

Comment: I have alreasy use the meta tag in head section:  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: I have also reinstall IE 11 in our system but again it is showing default 7 document mode.

Comment: Have any idea how to force setting to set default as edge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set IE11 Document mode to edge as default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034924/how-to-set-ie11-document-mode-to-edge-as-default)