# HTML5 Input type Date on FF - using Angular/Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is there a purely Angular/Typescript codebase without using any third party. Having issues with FF & IE11. Chrome is fine, can read the value, but the calendar doesnt show up when HTML5 input date is used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the following imports in polyfills.ts or you need to import shim.js.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: This might be the issue. IE 11 is installed but in the setting default may be less than version 9. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034924/how-to-set-ie11-document-mode-to-edge-as-default

Comment: try adding this in index.html   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;IE=11" />