# AngularJS Internet Explorer incompatibility

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, internet-explorer-11

I have written a frontend for Elasticsearch in AngularJS and it is working fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on some IE11 it is not working at all (some IE11 are working and some are not!)

Not working does mean:
 Angular variables are not not interpreted at all and I get it as `{{variable}}`.
 In gerneral my search engine does nothing (no controller call). It seems, that there is no AngularJS code executed at all and the site is a complete mess.

Any ideas?

**update**

I know, I had too less information but probably I am as confused with this issue as you.

Now I know, that IE11 always sets itself to "Document mode - 7" as shown in this question

> [How to set IE11 Document mode to edge as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034924/how-to-set-ie11-document-mode-to-edge-as-default)

There are probably two ways to solve this issue..

- My html page can force IE11 to use lates "Document Mode", or
- every single user hast to set "Document Mode" to the latest version (don't like that)

**Solution**

I added this

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

to my index.html to force IE11 to use its latest version, in this case edge

Comment: What does the console say? Have you tried changing compatibility modes? Could be a bug from a java method that IE doesn't support causing everything else to fail.

Comment: Console says everything fine.
The thing is, on some machines it is working on IE11 and on others it is crashing

Comment: Not enough information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary in cases that require debugging. There shouldn't be anything wrong with Angular. It is third-party or user code that creates problem - again, MCVE. When you approach browser incompatibility, the first thing to do is to apply all available polyfills, e.g. core-js . It's unlikely that there's no output in the console. If there was bootstrap problem (this is exactly what {{variable}} is about), there should be errors.

Comment: @estus please see updated question