# Object doesn't support this object?

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-11

What am I doing wrong here?

This code works in all other browsers except IE.

I am attempting to auto-fill a form input using the code below.

```
parent.setTimeout('var input = document.querySelector("form.media-library__upload-url .form-text-input");' +
                      'var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;    ' +
                      'nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, "http://lorempixel.com/400/200");' +
                      'var ev2 = new Event("input", { bubbles: true});' +
                      'input.dispatchEvent(ev2);', 0);
```

I have also tried using

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var input = document.querySelector("form.media-library__upload-url .form-text-input");
  var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, "http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
  var ev2 = new Event("input", {
    bubbles: true
  });
  input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
}, 0);
```

What is the proper way to do this in IE?

I am constantly getting this error

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
```

Comment: Which statement is getting the error?

Comment: @Barmar I believe it is ''Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11 Event constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work)

Comment: @JaromandaX  I am using version 11.0.16299.15 of Internet Explorer

Comment: The [`Event` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) is not supported in Internet Explorer. In order to create synthetic events, you need to use `document.createEvent` or a polyfill for `CustomEvent` as described in the linked question.

Comment: @Bizzet Which [document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034924/how-to-set-ie11-document-mode-to-edge-as-default) is the page loading under? The snippet may work under Standards or Edge mode, but will fail under Compatibility or Enterprise (under these, IE 11 can emulate IE 5.5 - IE 8).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I believe it is something to do with the New Event constructor not being available in IE11. How do I fix this?

Comment: @JaromadaX Do you have any other ideas with this information?

Comment: @Barmar Do you have any other ideas with this information?

Comment: @Bizzet Does this help? "[Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11 Event constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work)"