# WebSphere force IE-compatibility-mode?

Tags: tomcat, websphere, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a problem with IE-compatibility-mode.

I have deployed the same application both on Tomcat and WebSphere.
When I launch the application deployed on Tomcat, it start with IE 7 compatibility-mode as default.
Instead, when I launch the application deployed on WebSphere, it start with IE 11 compatibility-mode as default.

Why the application server changes the IE compatibility mode?
How I force compatibility mode to IE8 for the application deployed on WebSphere?

Comment: Are you referring to an HTTP response header?  Is your application trying to set it or do you expect the server to set it for you?

Comment: I don't understand if is the application or server to setting the compatibility.

Comment: I'm referring to ie compatibility mode show in internet explorer developer tools.

Comment: Presumably the HTTP response differs. Step one is identifying how it differs. You have to sort that out before figuring out why it differs.

Comment: There are multiple things that IE uses to determine whether or not to use a compatibility mode. Could be different headers, which @covener's suggestion indicates to check, or even just different domains. See like https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/796761 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29196966/796761